# does IE automatically change src to srcset tag?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Hi I'm trying to build a simple website. hosting through AWS. I've set my image code as the usual  etc. But when I host and check the code online it seems to change src to srcset. Is this a code issue or a hosting issue? I ask because on IE11 images don't show up.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with `and check the code online`?  How do you check that?  Is `src` changed  to `srcset` also in the other browsers?

Comment: check here https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill/issues/458

Comment: @t.niese like checking through developer tools on chrome or IE etc. and yes once hosted it seems to show up as srcset. Even when I wrote the code as src. Frankly it shouldn't matter, but IE11 doesn't support srcset, which is why I'm using src.

Comment: When you checked the code with Chrome, did you use "View page Source"/"Inspector > Sources" or did you look at the DOM under "Inspector > Elements"? If you checked the Source, and there the `src` is already changed to 'srcmap` and it happened server side, otherwise it happens clients side.

Comment: @t.niese on chrome checking the source it shows up as I intended - src, but when i inspect source on IE, the same code which should be src, is shown as srcset. So this means its happening on the server side right?